# Cout Not Printing the Return Value from the function

Tags: c++

I am trying the Infix to Prefix conversion and evaluation in C++. Someone here guided me and my converstion was resolved easily. But now I am having problems while evaluating it. The problem is that cout is not printing the return value from my function. Following is my code:

```
int PrefixEvaluation(string s)
{
    stack<int> st;
    
    for(int i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
        {
            st.push(s[i] - '0');
        } // if
        
        else
        {
            int op1 = st.top();
            st.pop();
            
            int op2 = st.top();
            st.pop();
            
            switch (s[i])
            {
                case '+':
                    st.push(op1+op2);
                    break;
                
                case '-':
                    st.push(op1-op2);
                    break;
                    
                case '*':
                    st.push(op1*op2);
                    break;
                
                case '/':
                    st.push(op1/op2);
                    break;
                    
                case '^':
                    st.push(pow(op1,op2));
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;
                    break;

            } // switch
        } // else
    } // for loop

    cout<<st.top()<<endl;

    return st.top();

} // PrefixEvaluation()

int main()
{
    cout<<"Prefix Evaluation: "<<PrefixEvaluation("+*^55/9/9*974")<<endl;
} // main
```

There is no error displayed. The console simply displays a blank screen. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The console simply displays a blank screen.

That is a problem. Not so much because your program crashed, but because you do not know *where* it crashed. The traditional remedy for this is to use a debugger, but in this case diagnostic output could be illuminating. Furthermore, for a project like this (a fairly simple console program), I would recommend having diagnostic output from the start so that you can verify your code as you go along.

What would be good diagnostic output? The core of `PrefixEvaluation()` is the stack `st`, so add a diagnostic line before every push and pop. This diagnostic should show the pieces you are working with. For example, when pushing a digit:

```cpp
std::cerr << "Push " << s[i] << '\n'; // Not converted to int
st.push(s[i] - '0');
```

(I use `std::cerr` because it is unbuffered, and because it is possible to separate `cout` and `cerr` output by redirecting one of them to a file.) Next example, when pushing an operation:

```cpp
std::cerr << "Push " << op1 << " + " << op2 << '\n';
st.push(op1+op2);
```

Do this for all the operations, plus the two `pop`s, and you should see why your program crashed:

```
Prefix Evaluation: 
Push 4
Push 7
Push 9
Pop  9
Pop  7
Push 9 * 7
Push 9
Pop  9
Pop  63
Push 9 / 63
Push 9
Pop  9
Pop  0
Push 9 / 0
```

There you go – you hit a division by zero error. *(Note: this is a reason to output the pieces without combining them. If the diagnostic was `std::cerr << "Push " << op1/op2 << '\n';` then the diagnostic would unhelpfully crash.)* To make your program stable (i.e. work even when the input is bad), you should check for zero before dividing. It's up to you to decide what the program should do in this case. Perhaps you simply want to inform the user and exit.

```cpp
if ( op2 == 0 ) {
    std::cout << "Division by zero!\n";
    std::exit(1);
}
st.push(op1/op2);
```

Don't forget to remove (or comment out) the diagnostics before declaring the project done.

---

You *could* get the same result from a debugger. Let the debugger break execution just as the program crashes, then look at the values of your variables at that point. See that `op2` is zero. It works, but if you want to find out why `op2` is zero, you often have to do another run, breaking multiple times. In contrast, the diagnostic outputs let you quickly trace the source of the zero to `9/63` with just one run.

The speed of tracing the state of your stack is the reason I find diagnostics helpful in this situation. Each test case can be quickly checked not only for the correct final result, but also for the correct computations along the way. The computations stand out, so if you know which should have been performed, you can scan the output to make sure each is present. This lets you check for many potential bugs with not much effort.

Comment: There are time traveling debuggers - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel_debugging e.g. for Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview

Answer (score 3):

So as @JaMit already explained above, it was a floating point exception. The problem was that I took variables `op1` and `op2` in `int`. Therefore, it was only taking the 0 from the previous value and not the complete number i.e `0.xxx`. So, I simply changed their data types from `int to double` and it worked perfectly. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score -2):

Wow, this is some inconsistency in the STL right there.

> std::stack<T,Container>::top
>
> reference top();
> const_reference top() const;
>
> Returns reference to the top element in the stack. This is the most recently pushed element. This element will be removed on a call to pop(). Effectively calls c.back().

No mention what happens when the stack is empty, no exception thrown when you try it. It just causes plain undefined behavior (exit 139 for me).

Now why is that relevant? Because what you wrote is a postfix evaluator and you feed it with prefix notation. The first character in the string is '+' so you pop 2 elements from the stack that is empty.

Comment: `Wow, this is some inconsistency in the STL right there.` Why is this inconsistent? I'm pretty sure all containers follow this 'convention'. If you call front/back on a vector or list for example and its empty you get undefined behavior as well. Operator[] on a vector performs no bounds check either (you call at if you want that).

Comment: The "effectively calls c.back()" covers this. There are only a few standard library types that work with `stack`, and all of them define `back` as being undefined behavior if the container is empty, e.g. [vector::back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back).

Comment: @cigien The inconsistency imho is that half the methods in the STL throw exceptions on error and the other half are UB. All methods with UB should be labeled `unsafe_*` like in other languages. But too late for that now.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Why should they be called unsafe? That's just normal - if you violate preconditions, that's your problem. If you are talking about `at` methods, those are exactly designed for checked access. So I see no inconsistencies BTW `unsafe_*` should be an operator by you logic ;) .

Comment: @Quimby That's the difference between throwing around loaded guns and having a safety switch on the gun. C++ has exceptions for out-of-bound and invalid argument and many more. So the default functions should check those conditions. If you know they aren't relevant and you want the code to be a tiny bit faster then you can use the unsafe_* functions that trust the caller and skip those checks. That's how many other high level languages do it.

Comment: There are no "default" functions, you have `operator[]` and `.at` and you can pick whichever you want or write your own.

Comment: I actually would call `operator[]` the default function and `at` the non-default because basically everyone used `x[i]` and `x.at(i)` is the exception. So imho the two function are the wrong way around, should have been design the other way around. Anyway, it's all wishful thinking. It's set in stone now and can't be changed.

Comment: You can create new containers or modify existing ones as you like.